# Tensorflow running out of memory inside a for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a tensorflow program that runs out of memory inside a for loop of this type after a few iterations:

```
for k in range(len(regressors)): 
    exposure_k = regressors[k].predict_values_tf(x)
    exposure = tf.where(regressor_index == k, exposure_k, exposure)
```

The function basically evaluates sequentially a python list of TF functions, and uses the results to fill certain elements of a common tensor. My questions are:

- Why does it run out of memory after a few iterations (and not immediately), considering that the loop simply overwrites the same variables (so, I would imagine, the same pieces of memory), and never increases the tensor sizes?
- Is there a way to write the same thing more efficiently, possibly in a parallel way? I tried to replace range with tf.range but then the index k becomes a tensor and I can no longer use it to retrieve an item in a python list with regressors[k]. I though of using tf.map_fn but I would have the same problem.

Comment: Two options from the top of my head: 1. You append exposure somewhere in the list.  2. Your regressor model is not in inference mode, so it calculates all the derivatives when you pass input through it, so by using more and more regressors you eventually run out of memory.

Comment: To answer your second question, we need to know what `predict_values_tf` does